clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) When trying to build unity iOS project in Xcode
I have an issue when trying to build unity project, it gives me this error:

ld: Undefined symbols:static
StoreKit.Transaction.Offer.PaymentMode.freeTrial.getter :
StoreKit.Transaction.Offer.PaymentMode, referenced from:static
(extension in
FirebaseAnalytics):__C.FIRAnalytics.logTransaction(StoreKit.Transaction)
-> () in FirebaseAnalytics17type metadata accessor for StoreKit.Transaction.Offer.PaymentMode, referenced
from:static (extension in
FirebaseAnalytics):__C.FIRAnalytics.logTransaction(StoreKit.Transaction)
-> () in FirebaseAnalytics17static (extension in
FirebaseAnalytics):__C.FIRAnalytics.logTransaction(StoreKit.Transaction)
-> () in FirebaseAnalytics17static (extension in
FirebaseAnalytics):__C.FIRAnalytics.logTransaction(StoreKit.Transaction)
-> () in FirebaseAnalytics17nominal type descriptor for StoreKit.Transaction.Offer.PaymentMode, referenced
from:_symbolic _____Sg 8StoreKit11TransactionV5OfferV11PaymentModeV in
FirebaseAnalytics17_symbolic _____Sg_ABt
8StoreKit11TransactionV5OfferV11PaymentModeV in
FirebaseAnalytics17protocol conformance
descriptor for StoreKit.Transaction.Offer.PaymentMode :
Swift.Equatable in StoreKit, referenced from:static (extension in
FirebaseAnalytics):__C.FIRAnalytics.logTransaction(StoreKit.Transaction)
-> () in FirebaseAnalytics17StoreKit.Transaction.Offer.paymentMode.getter
: StoreKit.Transaction.Offer.PaymentMode?, referenced from:static
(extension in
FirebaseAnalytics):__C.FIRAnalytics.logTransaction(StoreKit.Transaction)
-> () in FirebaseAnalytics17StoreKit.Transaction.Offer.type.getter
: StoreKit.Transaction.OfferType, referenced from:static (extension in
FirebaseAnalytics):__C.FIRAnalytics.logTransaction(StoreKit.Transaction)
-> () in FirebaseAnalytics17type metadata accessor for StoreKit.Transaction.Offer, referenced from:static
(extension in
FirebaseAnalytics):__C.FIRAnalytics.logTransaction(StoreKit.Transaction)
-> () in FirebaseAnalytics17nominal type descriptor for StoreKit.Transaction.Offer, referenced from:_symbolic
_____Sg 8StoreKit11TransactionV5OfferV in FirebaseAnalytics17StoreKit.Transaction.offer.getter
: StoreKit.Transaction.Offer?, referenced from:static (extension in
FirebaseAnalytics):__C.FIRAnalytics.logTransaction(StoreKit.Transaction)
-> () in FirebaseAnalytics17static (extension in
FirebaseAnalytics):__C.FIRAnalytics.logTransaction(StoreKit.Transaction)
-> () in FirebaseAnalytics17clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Things I already tried:

including StoreKit.framework into UnityFramwork
reinstalling, updating, removing repos in cocoapods
cleaning builds, rebuilding unity project
Using $(inherited)
Removing pod file completely and installing it
Cleaning cache


do you have the newest xcode version installed?

the StoreKit.Transaction.Offer.PaymentMode.freeTrial requires iOS 17.2. so you need to have Xcode 15.2 or higher installed.
